Audio not loading from a specific url on IOS but other urls work
I'm using twilio conversations to send messages. I have configured audio, video and text messages. On Android device, everything works fine. On IOS as well, the video functionality works fine. It is just that the audio URL does not get loaded using createAsync() function.
I've tried various things. I opened the said url in a browser, downloaded the file, placed it on a temporary server and then used that url and it worked.
I just don't get why those specific audio URLs don't work?
const handleAudioPress = async (audioUrl: string) => {
    if (playbackInstance) {
      await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
      setPlaybackInstance(null);
      setCurrentPlayingUrl(null); // Reset current playing audio
    }

    if (currentPlayingUrl !== audioUrl) {
      try {
        console.log("going to play audio");
        console.log("the url is: " + audioUrl);
        
        setLoadingAudio(true);
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
          { uri: audioUrl },
          { shouldPlay: true }
        );
        setPlaybackInstance(sound);
        setCurrentPlayingUrl(audioUrl); // Set the current audio URL as playing

        await sound.playAsync();

        sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status) => {
          if (status.isLoaded && !status.isPlaying) {
            console.log("Playback status updated: ", status);
            setCurrentPlayingUrl(null); // Reset when playback is complete
            setPlaybackInstance(null);
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoadingAudio(false);
      }
    }
  };

The sample url is:
https://media.us1.twilio.com/ME1a85bdfc9697091334aaff90cf6ce2d9?Expires=1727359929&Signature=O6GqbUfAal1TG5HZd4YvuyAQAAcwrigw6-MAfe5vQINnu4h1~83ffJA3Xvm1LqlfPdB-N2-shWjTUB9trVTpzJ7c3wC9~6CA3-QB2FpptVranCeUcQN~IaWfFdelyDAKrk7HjN1vGWAJWWqV4urXa3~dRQXZSkwW7O5ETDgBIdOE-eEshBxLIHktQJAJD0zETHlN3siYemYrmqQ5wD9JIsbxkn1ZoW56DPDGYjBC-IcSegPt4~0Wv1JMkFz6XD-qhFr3OnadcxGOjk0G8cLjmQWqF4Cqv5VqAwfneb87egRrxz-vvxYdSFP5ZZ-e7rqJzrQP1tckkUWCA8RoA84hOg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJWF6YVTMIIYOF3AA
I tried to setup every audio functionality and tried out each and every solution I could find
const setupAudioSettings = async () => {
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: true,
      staysActiveInBackground: false,
      interruptionModeIOS: InterruptionModeIOS.DoNotMix,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true, // Ensure it plays even when iOS is in silent mode
      shouldDuckAndroid: true,
      interruptionModeAndroid: InterruptionModeAndroid.DuckOthers,
    });
  };

The result however remained the same, the audio does not load whatsoever.

I updated your handleaudiopress with a bit more logging to help debug the issue. But essentially it could CORS issues possibly.
const handleAudioPress = async (audioUrl: string) => {
if (playbackInstance) {
  await playbackInstance.unloadAsync();
  setPlaybackInstance(null);
  setCurrentPlayingUrl(null); // Reset current playing audio
}

if (currentPlayingUrl !== audioUrl) {
  try {
    console.log("Going to play audio");
    console.log("The URL is: " + audioUrl);
    
    setLoadingAudio(true);
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      { uri: audioUrl },
      { shouldPlay: true }
    );
    setPlaybackInstance(sound);
    setCurrentPlayingUrl(audioUrl); // Set the current audio URL as playing

    await sound.playAsync();

    sound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((status) => {
      if (status.isLoaded && !status.isPlaying) {
        console.log("Playback status updated: ", status);
        setCurrentPlayingUrl(null); // Reset when playback is complete
        setPlaybackInstance(null);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error playing audio:", error);
  } finally {
    setLoadingAudio(false);
  }
}};

